# Selection of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I work with Pandas dataframe.I want to aggregate data by one column and after that to summarize other columns.You can see example below:

```
    data = {'name': ['Company1', 'Company2', 'Company1', 'Company2', 'Company5'], 
            'income': [0, 180395, 4543168, 7543168, 73], 
            'turnover': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'income', 'turnover'])
    df

INCOME_GROUPED = df.groupby(['name']).agg({'income':sum,'turnover':sum})
```

So this code above work well and give good result. Now next step is selection. I want to select only to columns from INCOME_GROUPED dataframe.

```
INCOME_SELECT =  INCOME_GROUPED[['name','income']]
```

But after execution this line of code I got this error:

```
"None of [Index(['name', 'income'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: I am pretty sure your income is index lvl 0; one way you could do it is reseting the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `reset_index()` after `agg()`:

```
INCOME_GROUPED = df.groupby(['name']).agg({'income':sum,'turnover':sum}).reset_index()
#                                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ add this
```

Output:

```
>>> INCOME_GROUPED[['name', 'income']]
       name   income
0  Company1  4543168
1  Company2  7723563
2  Company5       73
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line

> INCOME_SELECT =  WAGE_GROUPED[['name','income']]

you probably meant `INCOME_GROUPED` instead of `WAGE_GROUPED`. Also, uppercase variable names are frowned upon unless global constants.

This only solves `"income"` being available as a column. By default, `groupby` makes the grouper column the index in the result; this is changable by passing `as_index=False` to it:

```
income_grouped = (df.groupby("name", as_index=False)
                    .agg({"income": "sum", "turnover": "sum"})

income_selected = income_grouped[["name", "income"]].copy()
```

Note also the `copy` at the very end to avoid the infamous SettingWithCopyWarning in possible future manipulations.

Last note is that since you aggregated all columns and did it with the same method ("sum"), you can go for

```
income_grouped = df.groupby("name", as_index=False).sum()
```